# How to fix issue when importing a "bad" OFX file into Microsoft Money (Sunset)

Tags: microsoft-money

I was importing an OFX file into Microsoft Money and something about the file cause Money to abort.  Restarting Money resulted in it exiting immediately each time because the import was still pending.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Barclays have made changes to the .ofx format which fails to import in MS Money, it is simple to fix but annoying to have to keep doing it every time I do an import.

I have found they have amended the "TRNTYPE" descriptors in the file, so download the .ofx file, and then open the file in notepad and change all the TRNTYPE descriptors to "PAYMENT" or another descriptor that you prefer that money is happy with and it then imports without a problem.

Hope it helps you too

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions worked:

1. Uninstall and reinstall the app (which is time consuming)
2. Open regedit and go to:
   Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Money\17.0
   Clear out the contents of the "Import Files" key.
   That key has the list of files that will be imported when Microsoft Money starts.  The original files are copied to temporary files in %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp.

Comment: Why not just move or delete the bad file?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it is because it copies the bad file to the location I mention above, so even if you delete the original file it will still try the import from the cached version.  So I believe you can either edit the registry or remove the cached copy, but I don't recall if I verified that.

Comment: The cached file in the AppData\Local\Temp directory does not have the original filename and does not have a *.ofx extension, so it is not obvious as to which file is the bad file (except perhaps by looking at the modification time).  The "Import Files" entry in the registry does have the filename.  If you find the correct file and delete it, that does work too, but you will get a benign "communications" warning when MS Money starts up the next time if the registry key is not cleared.